# How to create and search a non-binary tree in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, tree

I need to compare two tree-structured reports and show comparison results in a datagridview in vb.net. 
I think using tree structure should be efficient. But note that I DO NOT use a tree view to display results (I found a lot of help in tree view though). All I want to do is to construct two trees, and then search the trees and compare. I do not know how to write this in vb.net.

Comment: Here is one (not tested) http://www.vbdotnetheaven.com/uploadfile/sapnabeniwal/creating-generic-tree-in-VB-Net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A tree like this would consist of a class that contains a list of child nodes and one or more methods to search using recursion. A *very* simple example:

```
Class MyNode
    Public ChildNodes as new Collection(Of MyNode)
    Public Data as Object
    Public Sub Search(searchString as string) as Collection(Of MyNode)
    ....
    End Sub
End Class
```

The ChildNodes and Data are typical for Trees, the Search Method (and any number of other Methods) are specific to your task.

Comment: I'd also suggest you to add a reference to a parent node like this `Public Property ParentNode as MyNode`